# Specify Go version for go.mod file

Tags: go, heroku

I am deploying an application through Heroku.
I do `git push heroku master`

And I get this error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Fetching stdlib.sh.v8... done
remote: ----->
remote:        Detected go modules via go.mod
remote: ----->
remote:        Detected Module Name: go-getting-started
remote: ----->
remote:  !!    The go.mod file for this project does not specify a Go version
remote:  !!
remote:  !!    Defaulting to go1.12.7
remote:  !!
remote:  !!    For more details see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-a
ps-with-modules#build-configuration
remote:  !!
remote: -----> New Go Version, clearing old cache
remote: -----> Installing go1.12.7
remote: -----> Fetching go1.12.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz...
remote: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
remote: tar: Child returned status 1
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to autoattack.
```

I think it's a problem with the new Go version and for this reason I want to use a previous one.

This is my go.mod file:

```
module go-getting-started

go 1.12

...
```

I tried to change `go 1.12` to `go 1.11` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try the previous exact revision: `go 1.12.6`

Comment: If i change "go 1.12" in "go 1.12.6" in the go.mod file, it doesn't change anything. It seems that it's not the correct way to set Go version.
Because I get: `The go.mod file for this project does not specify a Go version`

Comment: Without Go modules, you can set Go version by adding a `GOVERSION` environment variable (heroku Settings page). Try adding `GOVERSION=go1.12.6`.

Answer (score 49):

You could add a directive `// +heroku goVersion go1.11` in your `go.mod` file.

```
module somemodule

// +heroku goVersion go1.11
go 1.11

require (
    // ...
)
```

Then it should look like this.

```
remote:        Detected go modules via go.mod
remote: ----->
remote:        Detected Module Name: somemodule
remote: ----->
remote: -----> New Go Version, clearing old cache
remote: -----> Installing go1.11
```

Documentation: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#go-module-specifics

> ### Go Module Specifics
>
> You can specify specific package spec(s) via the `go.mod` file's `// +heroku install` directive (see below).
>
> `// +heroku goVersion <version>`: the major version of go you would
> like Heroku to use when compiling your code. If not specified this
> defaults to the buildpack's [DefaultVersion].

Comment: saved my day... so much time wasted, for lack of documentation.

Comment: the answer is helpful

Answer (score 11):

You can set the Go version to be used by adding a `GOVERSION` environment variable. You can do this on the Heroku Settings page of your project.

You may set the previous (working) revision by adding `GOVERSION=go1.12.6`.

This is documented at [Heroku Go Support: Go versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-support#go-versions):

> If you need to select a specific minor revision (e.x. go1.8.7) for any reason you will need to hand edit the appropriate metadata file or set the `$GOVERSION` environment variable...