# Why is this Go build failing on Heroku? It builds locally with no issue

Tags: go, heroku, deployment, build

Is anyone able to tell me why this build has failed on heroku?

I've tried finding substitute packages and tidying the mod file, even deleting it and redoing it.

here is my build log

```
    Overview Resources Deploy Metrics Activity Access Settings
Activity Feed  Build LogID f8e9d5ce-0d8f-4e8e-8b2a-661c4d1f68f7
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Go app detected
-----> Fetching stdlib.sh.v8... done
-----> 
       Detected go modules via go.mod
-----> 
       Detected Module Name: github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-xxxxxx
-----> 
 !!    The go.mod file for this project does not specify a Go version
 !!    
 !!    Defaulting to go1.12.17
 !!    
 !!    For more details see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-apps-with-modules#build-configuration
 !!    
-----> Using go1.12.17
-----> Determining packages to install
       
       Detected the following main packages to install:
            github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-xxxxxx
       
-----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-companion 
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2/ast
github.com/agnivade/levenshtein
github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2/gqlerror
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql
# github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql
../codon/tmp/cache/go-path/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/error.go:21:5: undefined: errors.As
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/errcode
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2/lexer
github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru/simplelru
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2/parser
github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru
github.com/gorilla/websocket
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2/validator
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/playground
github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-xxxxxx/graph/model
github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-xxxxxx/database
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/introspection
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2/validator/rules
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my go.mod file:

```
module github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-xxxxxx

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/99designs/gqlgen v0.13.0
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.5.0
    github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.1 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v0.0.0-20180220230111-00c29f56e238 // indirect
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1 // indirect
    github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2 v2.1.0
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.8 // indirect
)
```

I'm at a complete loss, I suspect it has to do with an incorrect version, but the build log doesn't give me much to go on. How can I diagnose this kind of issue in the future?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you access the Heroku instance and try to build it manually and see if there are any errors

Comment: `undefined: errors.As` seems like your building with an old version of go.

Comment: @JimB, How can I tell heroku which version of GO I want to use if it's already in my mod file?

Comment: Google readily turns up documentation on the subject. mentioning `GOVERSION` as well as https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#go-module-specifics

Comment: @JimB Was just coming back myself to mark this complete, as I found in the docs (missing this late last night, looking at it too long) specifying // +heroku goVersion go1.15 in my mod file fixed this issue. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Duplicate of [Specify Go version for go.mod file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968852/specify-go-version-for-go-mod-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a directive `// +heroku goVersion go1.15` in your `go.mod` file.

```
module somemodule

// +heroku goVersion go1.15
go 1.15

require (
    // ...
)
```

Then it should look like this.

```
remote:        Detected go modules via go.mod
remote: ----->
remote:        Detected Module Name: somemodule
remote: ----->
remote: -----> New Go Version, clearing old cache
remote: -----> Installing go1.15
```

Documentation: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#go-module-specifics

> ### Go Module Specifics
>
> You can specify specific package spec(s) via the `go.mod` file's `// +heroku install` directive (see below).
>
> `// +heroku goVersion <version>`: the major version of go you would
> like Heroku to use when compiling your code. If not specified this
> defaults to the buildpack's [DefaultVersion].

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to mark this one complete, I figured out that by specifying in the go mod file

// +heroku goVersion go1.15

Go buildback supports arbitrary comments specifiying versioning before build.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#go-module-specifics

Thank you as well to user @JimB for pointing me in the right direction.